# How to manually set axis range in Plot?

Tags: plotting

I am using `Table` to plot the time steps of a function. However, since there are a lot of decimal places in the x-axis, they are all cramped up :
[image]

I would like to multiply the numbers in the x-axis by $10^4$ so that the decimals drop out. How do I do this?

Comment: You may also find some use for `ScalingFunctions`.

Comment: It would help to have an example. My first few attempts suggest the problem is handled automatically in V13. (People here generally like users to post code as *Mathematica* code instead of just images or TeX, so they can copy-paste it. It makes it convenient for them and more likely you will get someone to help you. You may find [the meta Q&A, How to copy code from Mathematica so it looks good on this site,](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those are called [`Ticks`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Ticks.html). You could try adding the following option in your `Plot`:

```
Ticks -> {Table[{i/10^4, i}, {i, 0, 15}], Automatic}
```

Comment: @ForacleFunacle - Or for a plot with a `Frame` they are called `FrameTicks`

Answer (score 5):

#### Introduction

*[Evolution notice: I forgot to scale the vector field in `StreamPlot` and `VectorPlot`; now fixed.  Also nonstandard evaluation in Mathematica takes time to find out if you've thought of all the cute things that can be done: `%` now seems to work, though perhaps I was too clever and it will need fixing.]*

This started as simple idea: Post-process `Graphics[]` to translate/scale the coordinates and update ticks. I was needing to plot over a range `x0 <= x <= x0 + dx`, where `dx` was orders of magnitude smaller than `x0`, and I wanted the ticks to indicate the increments from a base point near `x0` in terms of units on the scale of `dx`. Applying those ideas to the OP's problem, limiting it to scaling only, seemed rather easy.  However, the plotting functions handle coordinate transformations of graphs very nicely for the most part, which shows up in the "Get Coordinates" tool and `ScalingFunctions`. Little by little, the idea evolved into supporting more robustly those features of which I am aware.

The function `sciAxes[]` now hijacks the plot command and does some pre- and post-processing.  The preprocessing includes scaling the variables and function and overriding the setting of `AxesLabel`.  The postprocessing (1) fixes the coordinate tool function, which probably will have bad interactions with a user-specified `CoordinatesToolOptions`, and (2) adds a tick to the x and y frame axes to serve as labeling of the scaling.  Step (2) is unnecessary if the plot does not have a `Frame`, but it is done anyway at present. This means that `Show[%, Frame -> True]` on a frameless plot `%` would show the scaled frame ticks with the scaling labels.  A weakness of `sciAxes[]` is that for single-variable plotters like `Plot`, one needs an estimate of the `PlotRange`. This is done by plotting with `PerformanceGoal -> "Speed"`.  It would be more robust, but slower, to just use the user's plot command to get an accurate estimate of the plot range.

Very simple interface:

```
sciAxes[Plot[...]]     (* scale both axes *)
sciAxes[Plot[...], 1]  (* scale just the x axis (first coordinate) *)
sciAxes[Plot[...], 2]  (* scale just the y axis (second coordinate) *)
```

For `Plot`, you may substitute other Cartesian, 2D, function-plotting commands (`ContourPlot`, `ReImPlot`,..., but not the non-Cartesian `PolarPlot`, not `ListPlot`).

#### Examples

```
sciAxes@
 Plot[Exp[10 Sin[10^7 t]], {t, 2*^-5, 2*^-5 + 12*^-7}, PlotRange -> All]

sciAxes[
 Plot[Exp[10 Sin[10^7 t]], {t, 2*^-5, 2*^-5 + 12*^-7}, PlotRange -> All],
 1] (* scale just the x axis *)
```

[image]
[image]

With `ScalingFunctions` and other plotting functions:

```
sciAxes[Plot[
  Exp[(10^6 t) Sin[10^4 Sqrt[t]]^2], {t, 2*^-7, 2*^-5 + 12*^-7}, 
  ScalingFunctions -> {"Log", "Log"}, PlotRange -> All]]

sciAxes[ReImPlot[Cos[t^2/4 + I*t], {t, 0, 10}], 2] (* only y axis scaled *)
```

[image]
[image]

It also works on 2D plotters of two-variable functions, such as `ContourPlot` and `StreamPlot`.  It's particularly useful for `StreamPlot`, whose plot depends on the `EuclideanDistance` metric, since `sciAxes` rescales the region to be closer to square.

```
{ {-(y - 1000) 150/2000, (x - 75) 2000/150},
  {(x - 75), (y - 1000)} };
{StreamPlot[%, {x, 1, 150}, {y, 1, 2000}],
 sciAxes@StreamPlot[%, {x, 1, 150}, {y, 1, 2000}]}
```

[image] 
[image]

#### Alternative: No-op scaling functions

Note that adding `ScalingFunctions -> {{1 # &, 1 # &}, Automatic}`, where the function `1 # &` is not ***identically*** `# &` or `Identity` results in a different tick function being called that might meet the OP's needs, although the ticks seem always to be irregularly spaced.

```
Plot[Sin[10^7 t], {t, 2*^-5, 2*^-5 + 12*^-7},
 PlotRange -> All, 
 ScalingFunctions -> {{1 # &, 1 # &}, Automatic}]
```

[image]

#### Code

```
(*" sciAxes[] - scales axes by nearest power of 10
    - sciAxes plots twice sometimes, once to get ~PlotRange
    - Variables must be symbols 
    - FrameTicks and the Get Coordinates tool needed hacking
    - Works on plot call, not on Graphics[] (TBD?)
*)
sciAxes // ClearAll;
sciAxes // Attributes = {HoldAll};
(* UTILITIES *)
(*" prToScaleLabel[]
    Convert PlotRange to scales and labels
*)
prToScaleLabel // ClearAll;
prToScaleLabel[pr_, axes_] := Module[{scale, label},
   scale = 0.8 Max /@ Abs@pr // Log10 // Floor;
   scale = ReplacePart[scale, 
     Thread[Complement[{1, 2}, Flatten@{axes}] -> 0]];
   label = Row[{"\[Times]", 10^HoldForm[#]}] & /@ scale;
   label = ReplacePart[label, 
     Thread[Complement[{1, 2}, Flatten@{axes}] -> None]];
   scale = 10^scale;
   {scale, label}
   ];
(*" addFrameTicksTooltip[]
    Optional: Add Tooltip to frame tick labels to show scaling
    - Also adds a "tick" at the end/top
    TBD: Whether to omit scale == 1
    TBD: Whether to do same for Ticks
*)
addFrameTicksTooltip // ClearAll;
addFrameTicksTooltip[plotter_, label_] := Function[plot,
   If[TrueQ[$VersionNumber >= 13.0],
    (* AbsoluteOptions was fixed for ticks in V13.0.0 *)
    Show[plot, FrameTicks ->
      MapThread[
       With[{lasttick = First@
            MaximalBy[Cases[#1, {t_?NumericQ, __}, Infinity], First]},
         Insert[
          (* uncomment code to not mark x10^0 scalings: *)
          #1 /. s_String /; StringLength[s] > 0 (*&&ReleaseHold[#2]!=1*) :>
               Tooltip[s, Row[{s, " ", #2}]],
          {First@lasttick, #3[lasttick[[2]]], {0., 0.}},
          {1, 1}]
         ] &,
       {OptionValue[plotter, 
         AbsoluteOptions[Show[plot, Frame -> True], FrameTicks], 
         FrameTicks],
        Reverse@label,
        {
         Function[{ticklabel}, 
          Column[{Last@label, ""}, 
           Spacings -> 
            If[StringQ@ticklabel && StringLength@ticklabel > 0, 1.5, 
             0.]]], 
         Function[{ticklabel}, 
          Row[{If[StringQ@ticklabel && StringLength@ticklabel > 0, 
             Spacer[15 + 10 StringLength@ticklabel], Spacer[20]], 
            First@label}]]}}
       ]
     ],
    (* TBD: Message? *)
    plot
    ]
   ];
(*" fixCoordinatesTool[]
    Optional: Fixes (scales) _default_ Get Coordinates tool 
    - Hacks internal options to compose with ScalingFunctions
      but documented System`CoordinatesToolOptions seems not  
      to play well with Scaling Functions either
*)
fixCoordinatesTool // ClearAll;
fixCoordinatesTool[plotter_, scale_] := Function[{plot},
   With[{fns = Function /@ (#*scale)},
    With[{xnew = First[fns], ynew = Last[fns]},
     Switch[OptionValue[plotter, Options@plot, Method]
      , _?(! FreeQ[#, "CoordinatesToolOptions"] &),
      plot /. {
        HoldPattern[
          opt : "DisplayFunction" | "CopiedValueFunction" -> 
           Verbatim[Function][{xfn_[xc_], yfn_[yc_]}]] :> 
         With[{xnew2 = xnew@*xfn, ynew2 = ynew@*yfn},
          opt -> Function@{xnew2[xc], ynew2[yc]}
          ]
        }
      , _List,
      plot /. 
       HoldPattern[Method -> methops_] :>
        Method -> Append[methops,
          "CoordinatesToolOptions" -> {
            "DisplayFunction" -> ({xnew[#[[1]]], ynew[#[[2]]]} &), 
            "CopiedValueFunction" -> ({xnew[#[[1]]], ynew[#[[2]]]} &)}
          ]
      , _,
      Show[plot, Method -> {
         "CoordinatesToolOptions" -> {
           "DisplayFunction" -> ({xnew[#[[1]]], ynew[#[[2]]]} &), 
           "CopiedValueFunction" -> ({xnew[#[[1]]], ynew[#[[2]]]} &)}}
       ]
      ]
     ]]];
(* MAIN METHODS *)
(*" sciAxes[]
    - 'call' unused; 'axes' specify which to scale
    - 2D Graphics[] plotters implemented (only)
    - Single and two-variable signatures (e.g. Plot, ContourPlot)
    - Can't add label to axes when there's a Frame; hence the
      addFrameTicksTooltip[] hack
*)
sciAxes[
   call : plotter_[f_, {x_Symbol, a_, b_}, {y_Symbol, c_, d_}, opts___?OptionQ],
   axes_ : {1, 2}] :=
  Module[{scale, label, $var},
    SetAttributes[$var, HoldAllComplete];
    MakeBoxes[$var[t_], form_] := MakeBoxes[t, form];
    {scale, label} = prToScaleLabel[N@{{a, b}, {c, d}}, axes];
    (* generate plot *)
    Block[{x, y},
       x = $var@x*First@scale;
       y = $var@y*Last@scale;
       With[{ff = f /. {
            vf : {{_, _} ..} /; MatchQ[plotter, StreamPlot | VectorPlot] :> 
              (#/scale & /@ vf),
            vf : {_, _} /; MatchQ[plotter, StreamPlot | VectorPlot] :>
              vf/scale}},
        plotter[ff,
         {$var@x, a/First@scale, b/First@scale},
         {$var@y, c/Last@scale, d/Last@scale},
         AxesLabel -> label,
         opts]
        ]
       ] // (* enhancements: *)
      addFrameTicksTooltip[plotter, label] //
     fixCoordinatesTool[plotter, scale]
    ] /; ! StringMatchQ[SymbolName@plotter, ___ ~~ "3D"];
sciAxes[
   call : plotter_[f_, {x_Symbol, a_, b_}, opts___?OptionQ],
   axes_ : {1, 2}] :=
  Module[{scale, label, plot, $var},
    SetAttributes[$var, HoldAllComplete];
    MakeBoxes[$var[t_], form_] := MakeBoxes[t, form];
    If[FreeQ[axes, 2],
     plot = 
      Graphics[{Point[{{a, 0}, {b, 1}}]}, 
       PlotRange -> {{a, b}, {0, 1}}],
     With[{prplotter = 
        plotter /. LogPlot | LogLogPlot | LogLinearPlot -> Plot},
      plot = prplotter[f, {x, a, b}, PerformanceGoal -> "Speed"]
      ]
     ];
    ({scale, label} = prToScaleLabel[PlotRange@plot, axes];
      (* generate plot *)
      Block[{x},
         x = $var@x*First@scale;
         plotter[f,
          {$var@x, a/First@scale, b/First@scale},
          AxesLabel -> label,
          opts]
         ] // (* enhancements: *)
        addFrameTicksTooltip[plotter, label] //
       fixCoordinatesTool[plotter, scale]
      ) /; Head[plot] === Graphics
    ] /; ! StringMatchQ[SymbolName@plotter, ___ ~~ "3D"];
```